# Html.ActionLink - I want to redirect to the same page but with different parameters

Tags: c#, html, razor, model-view-controller

I'm working on a new ePortfolio with different languages and for that I want to use html.actionlink that only changes the parameter language that I use. I have checked everywhere and can't seem to find it!

I have this code sofar

```html
@Html.ActionLink("Engelska", "Index", new { lang = "Eng" })<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Tyska", "Index", new { lang = "Ger" })<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Svenska", "Index", new { lang = "Swe" })<br />
<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Engelska - About", "About", new { lang = "Eng" })<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Tyska - Über", "About", new { lang = "Ger" })<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Svenska - Om", "About", new { lang = "Swe" })<br />
<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Engelska - Exercises", "Exercises", new { lang = "Eng" })<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Tyska - Übungen", "Exercises", new { lang = "Ger" })<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Svenska - Övningar", "Exercises", new { lang = "Swe" })<br />
```

But in the end I want to have only 6, three for the action methods and 3 for the languages, can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? 3 controllers (Index, About and Exercises) with a single action?

Comment: @rmorrin - Np, I am trying to achieve that I can have 3 Html.ActionLink that just switches the language of the current page and three other Html.ActionLink that goes into another action with the same language parameter then what it is now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.ActionLink` just renders a link for the specified action with the text you provide and allows optional route parameters to be passed (as you used). There's no real concept of a 'current page'.

With this kind of thing, you'd normally use a form POST to submit the language value, rather than a GET, which is what the `@Html.ActionLink` would use.

A quick example (forgive any syntax errors, typing from memory):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeLanguage", "Language", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Eng" name="lang" text="English" />
    <input type="submit" value="Ger" name="lang" text="German" />
    <input type="submit" value="Swe" name="lang" text="Swedish" />
}
```

This will submit the selected language to the 'ChangeLanguage' action of your 'LanguageController' (just making up names, you'll probably want to choose something more sensible!)

Then in your controller, you can do whatever logic you need to 'change' your language, persisting the setting in a cookie/session/whatever:

```
public class LanguageController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangeLanguage(string lang)
    {
        // change language, persist setting with cookie, session etc.

        // redirect to the page the user came from
        Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer);
    }
}
```

For the second part, regarding the links for other pages, you'll need to have some way of getting a localized string based on the current language, and use this as your link text. Let's assume a method `GetLocalizedString(key)` (again, making up names!) will return the correct link text for you:

```
@Html.ActionLink(GetLocalizedString("ExercisesLink"), "Exercises")
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly! :) Though I will say that Request.Referrer is actually Request.UrlReferrer! :)

Comment: Haha, you are quite right! Not too bad considering :) I'll edit my answer appropriately.